# In a velocity template I want to display a link which should not allow double click

Tags: velocity

In a velocity template I want to display a link which should not allow double click. Currently I am able to display the hyperlink but on double click, two separate windows are opening. I need to open single window even if I click multiple time on hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is just for rendering any text you provide to it as-is, it does not care about what language you are using the Velocity Template engine to render. It could be HTML or any other language.

This problem is particularly related with HTML. You could use css styles to make your link unclickable.

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;" >link text</a>
```

note the style attribute in the anchor tag above.